# Box 2d : What is the difference between a body and shape?

Tags: iphone, box2d

How a body is different from shape in Box 2d. Can't we create a body of some shape? Why it is required to create shape and body differently ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is very basic concept, some book/tutorial would be enough to get it!**
It is the way Box2D works, 1st you have to create a body and attach it to the b2world. And then you create a shape object and assign it to the body.
Body has properties like mass, density etc. which decides the behaviour of the body in the world.